# Small query - removing XML tags

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code that I wrote almost a year ago exactly (*1/9/2013*) and I would like to know if I wrote it well or if it can be improved.  I don't have any fun input or output, as these are not set results coming out of this column in the table.

```
-- =============================================
-- Author: Malachi (Name Changed to Protect the possibly Guilty)
-- Create date: 1/9/2013
-- Description: Will give a list of the Bond Conditions
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnBondConditionList] 
(
    @BondID int
)
RETURNS Varchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result Varchar(MAX)

    SELECT @Result = (Select Justice.dbo.uCode.Description as BondConditions
        FROM Justice.dbo.uCode INNER JOIN 
            Justice.dbo.xBondCondition ON Justice.dbo.uCode.CodeID = Justice.dbo.xBondCondition.ConditionID
        WHERE Justice.dbo.xBondCondition.BondID = @BondID
        FOR XML PATH (''))

    SET @Result = replace(@Result, '<BondConditions>','')
    SET @Result = replace(@Result, '</BondConditions>','<br />')
    Set @Result = LEFT(@Result, LEN(@Result) - 1)

RETURN @Result
END
```

I cannot change the tables.  Here are the table layouts:

**uCode:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[uCode](
    [CodeID] [dbo].[CodeID] NOT NULL,
    [CacheTableID] [dbo].[CacheTableID] NOT NULL,
    [RevisionID] [dbo].[RevisionID] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [dbo].[Word] NOT NULL,
    [RootNodeID] [dbo].[NodeID] NOT NULL,
    [EffectiveDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ObsoleteDate] [dbo].[ObsoleteDate] NULL,
    [UserIDCreate] [dbo].[UserIDCreate] NOT NULL,
    [TimestampCreate] [dbo].[TimestampCreate] NOT NULL,
    [UserIDChange] [dbo].[UserIDChange] NULL,
    [TimestampChange] [dbo].[TimestampChange] NULL,
    [FilterState] [dbo].[StateCode] NULL,
    [FilterSiteID] [dbo].[GUID] NULL,
    [Description] [dbo].[DescriptionLong] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_uCode] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [CodeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
CONSTRAINT [IXuCode1] UNIQUE CLUSTERED 
(
    [CacheTableID] ASC,
    [CodeID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**xBondCondition:**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[xBondCondition](
    [BondID] [dbo].[BondID] NOT NULL,
    [ConditionID] [dbo].[CodeID] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_xBonduCode] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BondID] ASC,
    [ConditionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This code was created to stuff everything from one column into a single column of a single record, which is then fed to a stored procedure that fills a datagrid.

Should I be looping this somehow (*I get a bad taste in my mouth just typing that*)?

I update this because I find myself using the same `FOR XML PATH ('')` Template for something very similar.

I cannot use `CONCAT` because I am using SQL SERVER 2008 (*wouldn't that be nice*).

With all that going into the Stored Procedure, the SPROC Renders something similar to this:[image: Image of Resulting Gridview]

Where the rightmost column is the column of the SPROC that was produced by a function almost exactly the same as above.

Comment: I think you might need to have an argument with somebody about separating the presentation from the data. The code smells because the requirements smell.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do not want the XML Tags, then do not add them!

This code frustrates me because:

- you have not given any indication as to what this code should be doing.
- you are embedding presentation-layer logic in the database layer
- you convert all the data to an XML document, and then strip all the XML tags from the result because this appears to be a *'cheap'* way to get all the data as a single result instead of multiple rows.
- you do not document this
- you use less-common features of the database (XML manipulation) without good reason, which locks you in to a single provider for the database ;-)
- there is no documented reason for why you strip the last character from the `@result`... this will strip the closing `>` from the last `<br />`, and will thus leave some invalid X?HTML? I presume? A bug?

As for some nit-picks:

- You should not be using `SELECT @Result = (...)`, but should, instead be using `SET @Result = (...)` [See the documentation for SELECT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx).
- you capitalize some of your query key-words, but not all. I recommend using whatever case you do **not** use for your columns. In your case, your db.schema.table.columns are all lower/CamelCase, so your keywords should all be full CAPITALS. Thus, you should have `SELECT` everywhere. You have one `SELECT`, and one `Select`. You have one `LEFT`, and two `replace`. Your consistency of convention should be improved.
- you do not use table-aliases for your query objects. Not only do table-aliases make the SQL more readable, but, if you need to change a table name for some reason (e.g. to get data from a view, or different schema), then you have to change multiple places, and could lead to bugs....

As far as I am concerned, this function should be removed entirely, and a simple presentation-layer system should be added that simply appends a `<br />` after each bond description from the query:

```
SELECT uC.Description
FROM Justice.dbo.uCode uC
INNER JOIN Justice.dbo.xBondCondition xBC
        ON uC.CodeID = xBC.ConditionID
WHERE xBC.BondID = ?
```

Comment: good answer,  I am taking Data that is Created by an application and displaying it on an additional information page of a website.  I agree with the `SET` and as far as the removing the last character, I think that there was something being returned at the end of the string other than the trailing `<br />`

Comment: I think that I did some `Dirty Things` to create what I wanted, in other words I agree with you completely.  when I get back around to this project again, I will think of about this and see if I can change it. it might tell me why I did this in  the first place as well.